# can not reload div tag using jquery ajax that contains some Php code

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have table in which data comes from the database.and I have the form on the same page which insert the data in the table.but when I insert data using `$.ajax` , it inserts record in database , but after reloading table in same function is not working, means it doesn't reload the table.
below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-8" id="value_table">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <?php 
            $q=$db->query('select attr_val_id,attr_val,sortorder,status from db_attribute_value where attr_id="'.$attr_id.'"' );
          ?>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Edit/Delete</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php $c=1; while($r=$q->fetch_assoc()){?>
                <tr class=" gradeX">
                  <td><?php echo $c; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $r['attr_val']; ?></td>
                  <td><a href="add_attribute_val.php?id=<?php echo $r['attr_val_id']; ?>&attr_id=<?php echo @$r['attr_id']; ?>">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
                    </a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default btn-circle" id="<?php echo $r['attr_val_id']; ?>" name="deleteRecord"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <?php $c++;}?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- /.table-responsive --> 

        </div>
      </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#attr_val_form').submit(function(event) {

    //$('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
    //$('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
    'attr_val' : $('input[name=attr_val]').val(),
    'attr_id' : $('input[name=attr_id]').val(),
    'sortorder' : $('input[name=sortorder]').val(),

    };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url : 'admin_operation.php?mode=add_attr_value', // the url where we want to POST
            data : formData, // our data object
            cache: false,

             success: function(data)
                   { 

                    if($.trim(data)== 'yes')
                    {  
                                   $("#value_table").html($("#value_table").html());
                        $("#notice")
                       .show()
                       .html('<div class="alert alert-success"<strong>Successfully !</strong> record added.</div>')
                       .fadeOut(3000);
                     }
                    else
                    {
                       $("#notice")
                       .show()
                       .html('<div class="alert alert-danger"<strong>Error !</strong>Record already exist.</div>')
                       .fadeOut(10000);
                    }
                  }

            })
            // using the done promise callback


    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: wich function you reloading ? and what means its not working? and where this form `? and ........... can you clarify good?

Comment: @echo_Me i am reloading the div tag with #value_table. i dont know how to reload. so i did use .html() method

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you think this line should do is get the data from the response and substitute the same tag in your DOM:

`$("#value_table").html($("#value_table").html());`

You should use something like that instead:

`$("#value_table").html($.parseHTML(data).find("#value_table").html());`

This code has not been tested, but the main idea is to parse the `data` parameter and the find the `#value_table` element.

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Answer (score 0):

As you say it seems like 'admin_operation.php?mode=add_attr_value' not success, try to call to always function instead success (for debugging it).
if the always function called successfully you have to return true from admin_operation.php
if not you have a problem on admin_operation.php after the insertion.